# Is it possible to perform databinding on Monotouch.Dialog.EntryElement?

Tags: monotouch.dialog

Is it possible to create databinding between a business object and the elements in the View Controller?  I have reviewed the documentation on the Elements API but I'm not seeing any references to binding.  We have chosen not to use the Reflection API for this application so that's not an option.

I am very new to working with Monotouch and iOS in general, so please forgive me if this question seems like I haven't done much research.   Any suggestions or links to documentation are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use monotouch dialog in reflection mode to show and collect data using attributes on the data members.

Beyond that, there are a couple of projects which have taken dialog further towards mvvm - search for monotouch.mvvm and mvvmcross - but you may find these overkill for your first monotouch/ios project.

- https://github.com/RobertKozak/MonoMobile.Views
- https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross

Comment: The slodge/MvvmCross project has some interesting code examples.  I'll do some research to see if we can get it to work.  Thanks!